Unresolved reference: json
When I build a kotlin project with cradle, I cannot use import org.json.JSONObject, and the json package is not in my library. How can I import it?
import org.json.JSONObject

I use kotlin with gradle. In build.gradle.kts:
dependencies {
    testImplementation(kotlin("test"))
}


Please don't add comments to clarify. Code is unreadable in comments. [Edit] your question instead. Quick guess: do you have the json dependency in your build script?

What is org.json.JSONObject and where is it coming from? Which of your dependencies provides this? Please [edit] your question and show us the gradle dependency.

Just add implementation dependency into your build.gradle.kts
dependencies {
    implementation("org.json:json:20240303")

    testImplementation(kotlin("test"))
}

